# Trying to reverse a batch for loop not as straight forward as I thought

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm working on a batch file that will automatically move files from a set of directories to and from an external hard drive to be scanned and moved.

The first step in this script is to move the contents of all directories (usernames are used for each) on the external drive to their appropriate directories (also usernames). Next files are moved in a similar manner to the external drive.

Here's more of a breakdown. On a server, everyone has their own directory (Last, First) with two directories inside Name-ToBeMoved and Name-AlreadyMoved.

I have a batch loop that pulls files from the "ToBeMoved" folders with no problem (and deletes them afterwards).

```
dir /b /s /a:d "\\SERVER\Path\Users\*ToBeMoved" | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" 
%%a in ('findstr ToBeMoved') do @xcopy /i /s /y "\\SERVER\Path\%%a\%%b\%%c" "E:\%%b\"

dir /b /s /a:d "\\SERVER\Path\Users\*ToBeMoved" | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" 
%%a in ('findstr ToBeMoved') do @del /S /Q "\\SERVER\Path\%%a\%%b\%%c"
```

However, I tried reversing this loop to pull files from the external drive and put them into the "AlreadyMoved" folders but haven't had any success.

```
dir /b /s /a:d "\\SERVER\Path\Users\*AlreadyMoved" | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" 
%%a in ('findstr AlreadyMoved') do @xcopy /i /s /y "E:\%%b" "\\SERVER\Path\%%a\%%b\%%c"
```

I tried debugging by turning `@xcopy` into `echo` to see what was being stored in the variables and everything looked perfect. Can someone help me see what I can't see? Why doesn't this loop work while the first one does?

**EDIT**: As requested, an example of what the output is when `@xcopy` is changed to `@echo`

(For clarity, FLast" is supposed to represent the same name from "Last, First" but first initial and last name.)

```
"E:\Last,First1" "\\SERVER\Path\Users\Last,First1\FLast1-AlreadyMoved"
"E:\Last,First2" "\\SERVER\Path\Users\Last,First2\FLast2-AlreadyMoved"
"E:\Last,First3" "\\SERVER\Path\Users\Last,First3\FLast3-AlreadyMoved"
"E:\Last,First4" "\\SERVER\Path\Users\Last,First4\FLast4-AlreadyMoved"
"E:\Last,First5" "\\SERVER\Path\Users\Last,First5\FLast5-AlreadyMoved"
"E:\Last,First6" "\\SERVER\Path\Users\Last,First6\FLast6-AlreadyMoved"
```

Perhaps this is also a good time to add even more clarity. The script should move files inside `"E:\Last,First"` into `"\\SERVER\Path\Users\Last,First\FLast-AlreadyMoved"`

The first loop moves files from `"\\SERVER\Path\Users\Last,First\FLast-ToBeMoved"` into `"E:\Last, First"`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre See the last paragraph of my question. That's exactly what I did.

Comment: sorry! Could you post a sample of the output in your question? maybe we'd have an idea then.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not a problem, I added an example of what the output looks like. I changed names of course to generic examples.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah lol I just noticed that. I corrected it.

Comment: Do you have some errors returned by xcopy when running your script? could you redirect the commands to another .bat file and try to call it?

Comment: note that you have a trailing backslash here `@xcopy /i /s /y "\\SERVER\Path\%%a\%%b\%%c" "E:\%%b\"` (working command), you don't have one on the command that doesn't work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well I'm running this particular loop in a stand alone batch file to test it. So nothing in the rest of the file should be interfering if thats what you're getting at. Also, I didn't notice the trailing backslash. I'm testing that now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Didn't solve the problem, I'm getting `Invalid Path 0 File(s) Copied` for all of these variations when I use `xcopy`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't see how the specifics could make any difference here. The only difference is that the characters are different. The format is identical.

Comment: sorry, cannot reproduce, so cannot help you without more information.